# I can't able to run the android application in AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I have multiple questions to ask. I tried my best to find the solution but still confused.

1) I couldn't able to run the android app in in the avd. Whenever I click the run as android application. Its only creating multiple avd but no avd is running my app. And I couldn't find any logcat messages. In the console its displaying these errors.

```
[2014-04-17 09:12:42 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2014-04-17 09:12:42 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-04-17 09:12:42 - MyFirstApp] Performing com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-04-17 09:12:42 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MotoG'
[2014-04-17 09:12:42 - MyFirstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MotoG'
[2014-04-17 09:13:47 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2014-04-17 09:13:47 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\Sanjay M\.android\avd\MotoG.avd/sdcard.img
[2014-04-17 09:13:47 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2014-04-17 09:13:47 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentere
[2014-04-17 09:13:47 - Emulator]
```

2) Sometime the `appcompat_v7` is not creating along with the project. Is it normal?

3) When I tried to create a Master flow activity its saying  "This template requires a minimum SDK version of at least 11, and the current min version is 8" - How to update the SDK version.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Instead of asking two questions in one, you would be better off asking two separate questions. This way you'll get the best possible solution for each question you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok,  For point 1 :**

Well As i thinks your application Target mode is by default selected as manual.

Select Run Tab in eclipse->Select Run Configurations ->
In that select Target Tab ->Select Automatic instead of manual
Click on Apply button and now hit run.

Now your app doesn't prompt for a device.

**For Point 2:**

appcompat_v7 is a support library in android, so if you already have this library some where in the workspace then it would not be created each time.

for more see [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html) .

**For point 3 :**

While creating the new project set the minimum sdk version to 11 in fourth one column from top.

see screen shot for help: (Note this pic only for demo, where to set minimum sdk version)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

add that in your manifest for setting min and target sdk

Comment: saiful, how you can create the manifest.xml without creating a project?